# IRIS Data set - Statistical Analysis, Mean and Mode

Tags: python

Trying to find out Mean and Mode for IRIS Date set. Getting a error message

```
import numpy as np

print("Means:")
print(np.mean(iris_setosa["Petal.Length"]))
Mean with Outliear
print(np.meanloc(np.append(iris_setosa["Petal.Length"],50)));
print(np.meanloc(iris_virginica["Petal.Length"]))
print(np.meanloc(iris_versicolor["Petal.Length"]))

print("\nStd-dev:");`enter code here
print(np.std(iris_setosa["Petal.Length"]))
print(np.std(iris_virginica["Petal.Length"]))
print(np.std(iris_versicolor["Petal.Length"]))
```

Which results in the following error Message when I run for Mean Function

> name 'iris_setosa' is not defined

Comment: can you show us the line where you define iris_setosa

Comment: No I am trying to read directly from the Data

Comment: iris = pd.read_csv("IRISR1.csv") - My file reference in Jupyter Notebook

iris.tail()

Comment: so if you don't have a data frame called "iris_setosa", you can't use it then, you have to use the data frame that you have which is "iris", otherwise you will get the error message "it is not defined".